# Ambiguous Method of Show and ShowDialog For Displaying Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am struggling between **Show** and **ShowDialog** method of Showing/Display of Windows Forms.
I generally use the show method instead of the `ShowDialog` method. And the `ShowDialog` method is used when I don’t want to show the forms at **ALT+TAB ToolWindow.**

The `ShowDialog` method shows **model window form** which is having limited access than the normal window form. The model window form is not accessing the value of the control and the object which already passed on normal window form. Hence, we have to provide the new value on each time or every time of new instance of forms which is a real example is as under.

```
//Purchase_Entry having a public method which is calling from form30 as under:

public partial class purchase_Entry : Form
{
    public purchase_Entry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Purchase_Binding()
    {
        mydgv.Location = new Point(0, 110);
        mydgv.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        mydgv.Width = panel2.Width;
        mydgv.Height = panel2.Height - 220;
        mydgv.TabIndex = 4;

        string connstr = "server=.;initial catalog=maa;uid=mah;pwd=mah";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr);
        con.Open();

        string sql = @"select billno,date=convert(varchar,date,103),ledgeraccount,totcts,rround,grosspurchase,taxes,taxamt,totdb,narrat" +
                     " from depurchasea where companyID=@companyID" +
                     " and transID=@transID" +
                     " group by billno,date,ledgeraccount,totcts,rround,grosspurchase,taxes,taxamt,totdb,narrat" +
                     " order by date,billno";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyID", label6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("transID", textBox5.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            textBox2.Text       = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["billno"]);
            maskedTextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["date"]);
            textBox1.Text       = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ledgeraccount"]);
            textBox9.Text       = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["totcts"]);
            textBox7.Text       = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["rround"]);
            textBox13.Text      = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["grosspurchase"]);
            comboBox1.Text      = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["taxes"]);
            textBox8.Text       = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["taxamt"]);
            textBox6.Text       = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["totdb"]);
            textBox3.Text       = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["narrat"]);
        }

        //mydgv.Columns.Clear();

        string mysql = "select srno,particulars,carats,rate,debit from depurchasea" +
                     " where companyID=@companyID" +
                     " and transID=@transID";
        SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(mysql, con);
        mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyID", label6.Text);
        mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("transID", textBox5.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter mydap = new SqlDataAdapter(mycmd);
        DataSet myds = new DataSet();
        mydap.Fill(myds);
        mybinding = new BindingSource();
        mybinding.DataSource = myds;
        mybinding.DataMember = myds.Tables[0].TableName;
        mydgv.DataSource = mybinding;

        mydgv.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Sr.No.";
        mydgv.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Particulars";
        mydgv.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Carats";
        mydgv.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Rate";
        mydgv.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Amount";

        mydgv.Columns[0].Width = 50;
        mydgv.Columns[1].Width = 500;
        mydgv.Columns[4].Width = 100;
        mydgv.Columns[2].Width = 100;
        mydgv.Columns[3].Width = 100;

        mydgv.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight;
        mydgv.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight;
        mydgv.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight;
        mydgv.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "f2";
        mydgv.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "f2";
        mydgv.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "f2";
        mydgv.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;

        int dgvsize = mydgv.Width / 17;
        mydgv.Columns[0].Width = dgvsize;
        mydgv.Columns[1].Width = dgvsize * 10;
        mydgv.Columns[2].Width = dgvsize * 2;
        mydgv.Columns[3].Width = dgvsize * 2;
        mydgv.Columns[4].Width = dgvsize * 2;
        mydgv.Refresh();

        if (textBox13.Text != "")
        {
            decimal res = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox13.Text);
            textBox13.Text = res.ToString("f2");
        }
    }

public partial class Form30 : Form
{
    public Form30()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {


        else if (textBox2.Text == "Purchase")
        {
             purchase_Entry pc = new purchase_Entry();
             pc.lbl6.Text  = pp.Form1.IDD.Text; //companyID
             pc.Purchase_Binding() //Calling public method of purchase_entry Class
             pc.ShowDialog(this);
             pc.textboxKeypress += new purchase_Entry.Action(pc_textboxKeypress);
             pc.purkeydown += new purchase_Entry.Action(pc_purkeydown);

         }
     }
```

The calling **Purchase_Binding()** method from **purchase_Entry** Form on **Show()** method is working very well, but if I use the same at the **ShowDialog()** method then it will display the records but the alignment of controls are changed. That means I have to issue a new value of each control size, height, width and companyID on the instance showing at the **ShowDialog()** method.

If so, then it will donkey works for me, because I have to redesign purchase_Entry on the `ShowDialog()` method.

**What is the best way?.** If I deal with the **Show()** method then the form will show at **ALT+TAB ToolWindow**, and I don't want to allow to show it at **ALT+TAB ToolWindow**. That's why I used the **ShowDialog() method** which will show as a model window form and will not be displaying at ALT+TAB ToolWindow.

And if I use the `ShowDialog()` method then I have to be ready to redesign it like donkey works. Isn't it?

Comment: Can't you have the method call n the constructor ?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, now form_load will execute only after `ShowDialog` so your label is not set, so it shows up blank

Comment: Why do you initialize label1 in the Form_Load method? Can't it be done in the constructor? The problem you are experiencing is simple as V4Vendetta points out.

Comment: @tafa, It's Just Example, I am always against of passing parametariz into form construction, because it will create a problem of overloading on each time of new instance of forms. and it is only one value, what happen if there should be more than one value available on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of the calls.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.moto();
    f2.ShowDialog();
}
```

The reason you do not see the effect of the moto call when using ShowDialog is, ShowDialog blocks the current executing thread until the form is closed, meaning the method moto is not called until the form is closed.

Comment: It's true that the changing the order of calls will solve the problems. but it will not allowed any further access of form2. and I wants the futher access of form2 hence I am not able to change the order.

Comment: What do you mean by further access ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta, Here further access means suppose if I have a ID value on form2 and my method is depend upon ID value than if I change the order of showDialog than It will throw error about blank ID value.

Comment: @tafa, See my new edit, the previous one is the small example of my real issue as above.

Answer (score 0):

Form.ShowDialog show the form in modal mode. It means that code bellow Form.ShowDialog will never execute while Form is opened.

In your case if your method depends upon ID, you must initialize ID **before** you call f2.moto(), e.g. before ShowDialog.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(int id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = id.ToString();
    }

    public void moto()
    {
        textBox1.Text = "MAHESH";
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(101);
    f2.moto();
    f2.ShowDialog();
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't use parametrized form constructor you also must init Id before calling ShowDialog.

Use the public property Id in the Form2 class:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void moto()
    {
        textBox1.Text = "MAHESH";
    }

    public int Id
    {
       set {label1.Text = value.ToString();}
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Id = 101;
    f2.moto();
    f2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I am against of passing paramterized in form construction. it's not good idea here.

Comment: So you can init id using other methods. For example, using public property Id in Form2. Or you can create public method ShowAndInitId(int id) { label1.Text = id.ToString(); ShowDialog();} And call this method instead f2.ShowDialog();

Comment: I am confuse can you edit your comments into your original answer with details

Comment: Than I must ask one precious question regarding the same and the question is: If I am going with showdialog than I have to pass Each parameter value on instance of form?. If form2 has control and many id than I have to pass again for the same?.

Comment: ... If form2's many controls are adjusted with each others height and width than I have to issue new value for the same. right?.

Comment: ... If so than Show() method is better than ShowDialog. But Show method also create problem of showing at ALT+TAB ToolWindow. Where as ShowDialog are not showing at ALT+TAB. That's why I am trying to know that which method is better

Comment: But both has create problem, I don't know how to deal with both method

Comment: See my new Edit which is the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you

This is your default constructor, make more as per the inputs

```
public Form2()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}

public Form2(int id)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if(id == 101)
        textBox1.Text = "MAHESH";
}

public Form2(string name)
{
    InitializeComponent();    
    textBox1.Text = name;
}
```

Make the call as you require and pass in the value, you can encapsulate further processing in different methods and make the call.

Load of the new form will only execute after `ShowDialog()`

Comment: Actually I am against of passing paramaterized  into form construction. because it is not good idea for utilize.

Comment: I think ShowDialog() Method has limited access then Show() method of particulars a form